# Segmentation fault in Sliding window maximum problem

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, deque

I tried solving Sliding window maximum using deque problem on Hackerrank([Deque-stl](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/deque-stl/problem)). I followed the algorithm given on [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sliding-window-maximum-maximum-of-all-subarrays-of-size-k/#disqus_thread) link. I didn't want to copy the solution so I tried coding my own solution. But my code is giving me "segmentation fault" and I don't understand what is wrong with my code. Can anyone please explain the fault in my code?

```
void printKMax(int arr[], int n, int k)
{
    deque<int> q;
    int l=0,j=k-1;
    q.push_back(l);
    while(j!=n)
    {
        for(;l<j;)
        {
            while((arr[l+1]>arr[q.back()])&&(!q.empty()))
                q.pop_back();
            q.push_back(++l);
        }
        cout<<arr[q.front()]<<" ";
        j++;
        while(q.front()<=j-k)
            q.pop_front();
    }
    cout<<"\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if the algorithm is correct but there are 2 lines that can give segmentation fault:

```
while((arr[l+1]>arr[q.back()])&&(!q.empty()))
```

The reason is that you are checking `q.back()` before `q.empty()` if it is empty the result will be an undefined behavior. Change this to:

```
while((!q.empty())&&(arr[l+1]>arr[q.back()]))
```

This way it will check if it is empty first and brake the loop if it is empty before checking `q.back()` and giving segmentation error.

Second line is:

```
while(q.front()<=j-k)
    q.pop_front();
```

I think you should check if it is empty like the first line.

Comment: I think the fix I provided for the first line is compiler dependent. Tell me if it didn't work and I will give a different implementation.